Adding Custom Music Disc in Minecraft 1.21.3
Custom Music Disc Not Playing in Jukebox (Minecraft 1.21.3)
I'm working on adding a custom music disc to Minecraft 1.21.3 Java Edition using a datapack and server-side resource pack. Here's what I've done so far:
Resource Pack:

Added welcome.ogg to assets/minecraft/sounds/.
Registered the sound in sounds.json.
I can successfully play the sound using /playsound minecraft:welcome @p and hear it correctly.

Datapack:

Added a music disc definition file at /world/datapacks/oraxen_jukebox/data/minecraft/jukebox_song/welcome.json:

  {
    "sound_event": { "sound_id": "minecraft:welcome" },
    "description": { "text": "§6Welcome §eSong" },
    "length_in_seconds": 180,
    "comparator_output": 12
  }


Gave myself an item with the jukebox_playable component set to minecraft:welcome.

Current Behavior:

The item tooltip correctly displays "Welcome Song," which suggests the datapack is loaded.
However, when I insert the disc into a jukebox, no sound plays.

Troubleshooting Attempts:

Tried using namespaces other than minecraft for the sound ID, but the behavior didn't change.
Verified that the sound file is accessible and correctly registered in the resource pack.

Question: What could I be doing wrong that prevents the custom sound from playing in the jukebox? Is there something additional I need to configure in the datapack or resource pack?
